# Passing multiple arguments is deprecated! Pass an options object instead

Tags: node.js, gulp

I use gulp4 when I run 'data' task I'll get the warning:

> WARNING!! Passing multiple arguments is deprecated! Pass an options object instead.

```
// Build data json
gulp.task('data', () => {
    return 
      gulp.src([ '**/*.yml', '!**/_*.yml' ], 
      { cwd: 'source/modules/*/data' })
        .pipe($.plumber(options.plumber))
        .pipe($.yaml({ space: '\t' }))
        .pipe($.mergeJson('data.json'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('tmp'));
});
```

If I remove `.pipe($mergeJson)`, the warning won't notify
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Solved. The `gulp-merge-json` plugin changed to require an object of options.

```
var options = {
    fileName: 'data.json'
}

.pipe($.mergeJson(options))
```